# Eclipse: Android Project: How to run shell script on build?

Tags: android, eclipse, build, build-process, build-automation

I have a build script that actually does calls ant to build the apk file and does some stuff on it and bundles again the dex files and calls ant to build the final apk and that APK is ready to be installed in emulator or device.

How can i do all this by just click on Run -> Run, or Project -> Build or some other eclipse command.

i want when i click on the Project -> Build Project, the shell script should run and i get the final APK ready and then by clicking on Run it will install to the emulator or APK.

How can i achieve this? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-92_project_builders.htm) describes how to build using ant from eclipse. Is this what you want?

Comment: thats what i wanted .. thanx